# Xlib: unexpected async reply (sequence 0x1cb4)!

Tags: eclipse, junit, swt, awt, junit4

I am unable to run Windows tester on SLED 10 machine. When I try to run test as JUnit plugin-in-test, eclipse launches and I see `Xlib: unexpected async reply (sequence 0x1cb4)!` error in console and eclipse does nothing. I googled and found n number post for the issue but no proper solutions. If anyone have encountered with the problem and found solution pls feel free to reply to this post.

Note: This link clearly describes about the problem `http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6386791`

Here is the config of my machine

```
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-noarch:core-2.0-ia32:core-3.0-ia32"
SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 10 (i586)
VERSION = 10
PATCHLEVEL = 4
SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 10 (i586)
VERSION = 10
PATCHLEVEL = 4
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this problem too. What I am trying to do is make a plugin for my Qt application that will move the mouse around and test the GUI. The mouse is moved around using X11 libs. The plugin launches a separate QThread and in this thread I make calls to Qt functions to retrieve information about widgets but I do not ever set any positions or anything. Maybe even calling Qt functions from another thread can also cause the error.